# Create domain shared contact in Gsuite using Contacts API in C#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-contacts-api

I am trying to create a domain shared contact in GSuite via the Contacts API in C# but unable to figure out how to POST the atom XML entry to the Feed URL as mentioned here : https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts/#Creating

I have tried following the older GData way mentioned here https://developers.google.com/gdata/client-cs but I get a "Execution of authentication request returned unexpected result: 404" error.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Hello !! ");
            //Get Auth
            OAuth2Parameters p = ContactsAuth();

            //Create a domain shared contact
            try
            {
                RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings("GSuiteAdminApp", p);
                ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);

                ContactEntry cn = new ContactEntry();

                Name n = new Name();
                n.GivenName = "Ice";
                n.FamilyName = "Cold001";
                n.FullName = "Ice Cold001";

                EMail e = new EMail();
                e.Rel = "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work";
                e.Primary = true;
                e.Address = "ice.cold001@xyz.com";

                cn.Name = n;
                cn.Emails.Add(e);

            }
            catch (Exception e44)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e44.Message);
            }
        }




//Auth for Contacts API
        public static OAuth2Parameters ContactsAuth()
        {
            string clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
            string clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";

            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/" };

            try
            {
                UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    ClientSecret = clientSecret
                }, scopes, "super-admin@mydomain.com", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("C:\\Temp\\A\\SharedContactsOauth")).Result;
                // Translate the Oauth permissions to something the old client libray can read
                OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();
                parameters.AccessToken = credential.Token.AccessToken;
                parameters.RefreshToken = credential.Token.RefreshToken;
                return parameters;
            }
            catch (Exception ex33)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex33.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

This gives a "request failed" error.

Comment: Have you considered using the People api instead.  It should give you the same access and you wont have to use the gdata library which is no longer supported.

Comment: Thanks Linda for looking into it. I checked People API but nowhere it mentions anything about creating "domain shared contacts" using the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to figure it out by stringing along code snippets from few different sources and some modifications of my own. Linda Lawton's https://www.daimto.com/google-contacts-with-c/ for the OAuth2 part using older GData API. Google's documentation on Contacts API v3.0 https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/ for mechanics of using the .NET client library for contacts and their (bit sketchy) documentation on "domain shared contacts", especially on using the proper FeedUri and Atom entries for new contact https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts/#Creating.

Basically what it boils down to is this - 
Use a GSuite Super Admin account to authrorize to Contacts API using OAuth2.0, then use GData Contacts .NET client library to create the new contact
by suppying your Gsuite domain in the method  and you are done.

Here's the full code which I have it working for me now:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Google.Contacts;
using Google.GData.Contacts;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
using Google.Apis.Auth;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace SharedContactsAPI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Hello !! ");

            //Get Auth
            OAuth2Parameters p = ContactsAuth();

            ////Create a domain shared contact
            try
            {
                RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings("GSuiteAdminApp", p);
                ContactsRequest contactreq = new ContactsRequest(settings);

                Console.WriteLine("Attempting to create a Domain Shared Contact in GSuite");
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                CreateContact(contactreq);

            }
            catch (Exception e44)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e44.Message);
            }
        }

        //Create Shared Contact
        public static Contact CreateContacttest(ContactsRequest cr)
        {
            Contact newEntry = new Contact();
            // Set the contact's name.
            newEntry.Name = new Name()
            {
                FullName = "Ice Cold005",
                GivenName = "Ice",
                FamilyName = "Cold005"
            };
            newEntry.Content = "Notes";
            // Set the contact's e-mail addresses.
            newEntry.Emails.Add(new EMail()
            {
                Primary = true,
                Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork,
                Address = "ice.cold005@xyz.com"
            });

            //Insert the contact
            Uri feedUri = new Uri(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("test.com"));
            Contact createdEntry = cr.Insert(feedUri, newEntry);
            Console.WriteLine("New Contact created successfully with ContactID = " + createdEntry.Id);
            return createdEntry;
        }

        //Auth for Contacts API
        public static OAuth2Parameters ContactsAuthtest()
        {
            string clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
            string clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/" };

            try
            {
                UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    ClientSecret = clientSecret
                }, scopes, "super-admin@test.com", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("C:\\Temp\\A\\SharedContactsOauth")).Result;
                // Translate the Oauth permissions to something the old client libray can read
                OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();
                parameters.AccessToken = credential.Token.AccessToken;
                parameters.RefreshToken = credential.Token.RefreshToken;
                return parameters;
            }
            catch (Exception ex33)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex33.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Use this Nuget Package Command to install required package:
`Install-Package Google.GData.Contacts -Version 2.2.0`